# I can not make remote session to the exchange server using c# using Kerberos authentication

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have 2 machines in the same local network, but in the different domains.

On one of them I have exchange server. When I try to connect remotely to the powershell from the machine A to the machine B(here is the exchange server).

I am able to make and import remote session if I use powershell console using Kerberos authentication. But the problem is that it fails on Authentication when I use c# approach, both using WSManConnectionInfo class or using powershell.AddScript(...) where I put the same script which is running fine in the powershell console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use punctuation marks, line breaks and code tags. It would make your question more readable. What is the link for? Sure that this is a question for StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not only when I try to connect over WSManConnectionInfo class in c#, I am also not able to connect remotely using powershell console.

I was confused because at some time I was able to run remote connection, so I wrongly assumed that code works from the powershell console, but not from the c#.

At the end problem was that Kerberos Authentication doesn't work anymore on my exchange server from some reason.